# Setting CRS for SCP within QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, scp

I am currently working with SCP within QGIS and am trying to classify the contents of a field (different flowers, grasses, bare ground etc.). I have loaded a raster image of my field and am now attempting to create my ROIS. However, when I try and create a new training file, I am asked multiple times to set the CRS for the field (I want to use WGS 84). Additionally, when I attempt to create a new ROI vertex, I am asked multiple times to set the CRS for the layer and each point. Lastly, I am not able to save the ROI and am prompted with a message saying that I do not have a raster layer loaded and that it cannot be projected.

I believe that I have set up my multiband image and RGB list correctly.

Does anybody know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, although the 2 CRS were the same.
I reprojected the input raster to its same CRS and then it worked!